# Nested for loop is not looping correctly in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, nested-loops

Im trying to loop through two object lists i have. below is the sample structure of those lists.

```
List<Model1> list1 = [ Model1(name: name1, isFavorite: true, amount: 1.0), Model1(name: name2, isFavorite: true, amount: 4.0), Model1(name: name3, isFavorite: true, amount: 5.0)];
List<Model2> list2 = [Model2(name: name01, isSubscribed: true, percentage: 1.0), Model2(name: name02, isSubscribed: false, percentage: 7.0), Model2(name: name03, isSubscribed: true, percentage: 3.0), Model2(name: name04, isSubscribed: true, percentage: 9.0),]
```

i' comparing name of each two lists.
i want to see if list1 contains any item from list2 and add them to a new list.
let's say only name1 = name01 and name2 = name02
then  list3 = [Model1(name: name1, isFavorite: true, amount: 1.0), Model1(name: name2, isFavorite: true, amount: 4.0),]
also to see when list1 is compared with list2 and list1 items that are not matched with list2 items add to another new list.
then list4 = [Model1(name: name3, isFavorite: true, amount: 5.0)]

i've tried with the following function nested for loop but my loop does not work as expected. can anyone help me to figure out this?

```
for (Model1 itemI in list1) {
 for (Model2 itemJ in list2) {
  if (itemI.name == itemJ.name) {
          list3.add(itemI);
          break;
        } else {
          list4.add(itemI);
          break;
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: Remove `break`s;

Comment: removing break adds the first item to both lists. it seems the loop does not run for all members in list1.

Comment: As everyone else is saying remove the `break` keyword. Also is you want to keep the loops running use the `continue` keyword instead of `break` this will continue running the loop if the condition is met. 1 could end if `break` if something went wrong and the other can end in `continue` meaning that it behaves as you want and you would like to continue your iterations.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist just removing the breaks won't solve what he tries to do. Because it will add a lot of duplicates to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
List<Model1> list3 = list1.where((e1) => list2.any((e2) => e1.name == e2.name)).toList();
List<Model1> list4 = list1.where((e) => !list3.contains(e)).toList();
```

Comment: Could you explain why and how? It would be helpful to the following people that come along and see this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have to add that Model1 and Model2 have different parameters here.

Comment: @jason_z what do you mean? this should work like you want it

Comment: what i mean is that Model1 and Model2 are two different models. Im just matching the name of each model element to see if matches or not. to my above logic

Comment: @jason_z yes that's what I'm doing. That's irrelevant for this answer

Comment: thank you @Ivo. this works well. accepted as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Break keyword is used to terminate the loops. So remove it.

Answer (score -1):

The ‘break’ code exit the loop when execute at first time. Remove it